# Print custom field in taxonomy template file (Drupal 7)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I’m using Drupal 7 and am trying to change the `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` file to display a custom field. The vocabulary has a Link field.

[image: vocabulary fields]

I want to print the link from `field_url` wrapped around the taxonomy term’s name. I’ve tried adding a `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` file to my theme with the following code but I’m not having any luck:

```
<div id="taxonomy-term-<?php print $term->tid;?>" class="<?php print $classes;?>">
    <a href="<?php print render($content['field_url']);?>">
        <?php print render($term_name);?>
    </a>
</div>
```

I think I must be targeting the Link field incorrectly — any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like there is no issue with your code. 
Tried Clearing Cache? 
Print the `$content` variable and check whether the Field you are looking for is avaiable there.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `render($content['field_url'])` will render field and return html with wrapper div etc. But we need just url. In template file we can obtain it from $field_url[0]['url']

Secondly, `$term_name` contains string, there is no need to `render()` it.

Thus your code should turn into:

```
<div id="taxonomy-term-<?php print $term->tid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
    <a href="<?php print $field_url[0]['url']; ?>">
        <?php print $term_name; ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

And do not forgive to clear theme cache after creating template files in your theme directory.